# Methods for searching a large face database

Tags: computer-vision, object-recognition, face-detection

I have a large face database, and I want to search through it. For example, if I input a new face image, the system would return the best N similarities.

I know that PCA, LDA, and Procrustes analysis are used for this, but it seems that I need to project all this large database into PCA space, and I don't know any library that can handle that.

Are there some tools, software, or a library for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can transform your problem into the following "given a set of vectors find the N ones with the smallest euclidian distance to the query", there are well-known methods (Ball-trees, Locality-sensitive hashing...) for solving it on large datasets. With this approach, PCA / LDA is thus just a pre-processing step for transforming the set of features produced by your feature extractor into a lower-dimensionality feature vector.

Comment: I want to use model like ASM(active shape model) for face recognition.

For example I mark by the hands points on 1st image and 2nd and then I want to compare them.

What metric I should choose?

My 1st assumption was to use simple euclidean distanse for 2D points, but before I need to "align" models for example calculate сetres of gravity and align, and then apply scale changes,also I can align by the axes of the ellipses, but I think it doesn't give good align results, I think I need some non linear cost function to "morph" from 1 model to another.